# MySQLi not inserting into table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert data into mysql table using mysqli but this code is not working and I am not getting any errors printed out.

What could I possibly be missing?

```
<?php
// if the form was submitted
if($_POST){

    // sql query
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO
                t_incident_persons (IncidentID, PersonID, KeywordID, description)
            VALUES
                (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    // if the statement was prepared
    if($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql2) ){

        //bind the values,
        $stmt2->bind_param(
            "iiis",
            $_POST['IncidentID'],
            $_POST['PersonID'],
            $_POST['KeywordID'],
            $_POST['description']
        );

        // execute the insert query
        if($stmt2->execute()){
    header('Location: details.php');
    exit;
            $stmt2->close();
        }else{
            die("Unable to add an incident.");
        }

    }else{
        die("Unable to prepare statement.");
    }

    // close the database
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's autocommit behavior. Try to close before connection before redirecting.

```
...
if($stmt2->execute()){
    $stmt2->close();
    header('Location: details.php');
    exit;            
}else{
    die("Unable to add an incident.");
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but without that block of code you've given I get an error: unexpected end of file.